# android network error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, сеть

запускаю простой пример для загрузки html страницы на реальной устройстве который подключен к интернету через wifi

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://www.vogella.com");
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  readStream(con.getInputStream()); 
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("QWER", "ERor");
    e.printStackTrace();
}


 private void readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("QWER", line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

это код запускал в eclipse и там работал норм... но на android постоянно выбрасывает Exception ...

ide anroid studio os android 4.4

в чем может быть причина?

Comment: выпадает NetworkOnMainThreadException? Если нет, то укажите какое и приведите стектрейс

Comment: Надеюсь, как выше спросили про ошибку, в потоке с сеткой общаетесь ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, проверьте AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Во вторых, вся работа с интернет соединением не должна выполнятся в UI потоке. Создайте отдельный поток и перенесите данный код туда.